# Configure Git clone options in Team City

Tags: git, teamcity

Team City supports the 3 checkout modes for git:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCDL/VCS+Checkout+Mode

None of these does a full git clone - as if you did a clone from command line - including all remote tracking branches.

Is it possible to configure TC to do a full git clone?

Currently the only way that seems possible is by running a command line build step that does a git clone, relying on git being on path and that you have stored credentials for the git host.

Comment: Have you found the way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

enabling all branches under Branch specification section of VCS root setting should help.

[image]

Comment: That just specifies which branches will be monitored not what will actually be checked out. TC will still do a single branch checkout - the one that it currently finds has a change. E.g. check the details of the Updating sources: agent side checkout log

Comment: Looks like limitation of teamcity no way to pull all branches in VCS settings.